# iOS: Relation between firestore authentication and database

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, relationship

I'm working with Firestore database. My app does't have singup option for users. So I need to add user from Firestore console. I have following issue with the relationship of documents and authentication:

1. I created user in Authentication section with email/password.
2. I added three records in "Table" and two records with repeated email
   ID.
3. I login with authenticate user and fetch all the records from
   "Table".

Now I have two records with same email ID. So how to recognise which records is related to authenticated user.

Comment: What I would advise is the following:
(manually or programmatically) Create a user in Authentication, from this you get a unique UID. With this unique uid create a document in your Users collection.

When a user is logged in, you can easliy fetch the user's information by simply opening the corresponding document: db.collection("users"). document(<the uid>).

I can't really go into your approach since it's quite unclear to me, why and what you add in the "Table" and how you end up with the records with the same email?

Comment: @Egghead Umm I don't want to create user from app. That is the problem. If I do signup from app then it will work fine coz I will add UID to document while createing user.

Comment: if you manually create a user on console.firebase.google.com, you still get a UID which you can use.

How do you currently create the documents in firestore?

Comment: Manually by tapping Add Collection then tapping on add document and then tapping on add fileds.

Comment: So you can add the generated UID there right? As the document ID: https://i.ibb.co/nRpqDBb/Screenshot-2019-04-23-at-15-00-41.png

Comment: Hold up. Firebase Authentication will not allow duplicate email addresses as the identifier. Additionally, collections and documents cannot have duplicate keys (documentID). There must be more to the question. Please update with specific info about how documents or collections are being created, how the identifier is being set and what they are being set to. Include a snippet of your Firebase structure. To answer the question; how do you relate a user to their data? Storing the users UID as a child of that data is one way, optionally, storing the documentID with the UID is another.

Comment: @Jay I know we can't duplicate email addresses in Authentication but we can add in documents....

Comment: @Egghead Here is the screenshot .https://ibb.co/F3pDprN  and https://ibb.co/n7dj4zL

Comment: @SarabjitSingh could you expand the question with the reason you add two documents? especially since you manually add them and choose to add tow documents. Whereafter you ask how to find which one fits the user?

Comment: The question is still unclear which is why we are all posting comments. Why are you creating two records with the same email address? Can you include the structure on your question? You cannot add two documents with the same documentID so we don't know what's being added or why.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you can do a few things:

1. You can sign in anonymously using:

   ```
   Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
      // enter code here
   }
   ```

Do the above for first time, and store the UID in user default.
Here you will get a user id from authResult. 
Also here you do not need email id or password.

OR:

2. Create a node with deviceId so that you can get data for that specific device.

Hope this helps.